# SonataMediaBundle get image width and height

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have an image in my template:

```
{% media picture.media, 'reference' %}
```

How can I get width and height of that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dunno which answer you are looking for, since this question can be answered in different ways, so I'm trying to answer all of those ways.

---

## Getters on Media objects

If you're just interested in getting the values from your media object, you can just simply call:

```twig
{{ picture.media.width }}
{{ picture.media.height }}
```

## Media rendering

Sonata's twig-extension for rendering medias will automatically add width/height to your html.

```html
<!-- twig -->
{% media picture.media, 'reference' %}

<!-- renders -->
<img src="path/to/media" alt="media" width="256" height="256" />
```

## Media Contexts

It will always render the full media file, regardless of it's size.
Doing the same with the thumbnail-tag provided by SonataMedia lets you define different sizes which than will be rendered in size you would have configured. Take a look at [introduction to SonataMedia's context configuration](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html).

```yaml
# app/config/config.yml

sonata_media:
    contexts:
        news:
            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
```

```html
<!-- twig -->
{% thumbnail picture.media, 'small' %}

<!-- renders (note, height will be recalculated automatically by it's ratio) -->
<img src="path/to/media" alt="media" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for!